# TWIG variables between templates?

Tags: symfony, twig

Beeing completely new to TWIG (it's also my first templating language) I have a little problem understanding the variables.

Heres what I need:

I have 2 layouts. One inheriting from the other.
On the first one I need to put an if on a div to add a class if on the second layout a variable is declared.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Every variables given in `render` are passed along all templates being rendered. It means that if `foo` is given through `render` of `page.html.twig` and `page.html.twig` includes/inherits `layout.html.twig`, `layout.html.twig` will have access to `foo` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say in Symfony you write:

```
return $this->render('::index.html.twig', array('variable' => $somevar));
```

And 'index.html.twig' looks like this:

```
{% extends '::foo.html.twig' %}

{# some contents #}
```

and 'foo.html.twig' looks like this:

```
{{ variable }}
```

It should just work. If it doesn't work, post some code and errors here, and I'll see what I can do to help. Obviously this example is unrealistic, but all templates should have access to all variables passed from Symfony, in addition to the global ones and anything you define as Twig extensions.